# Node.js server is not started after reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, upstart

My Node.js server upstart job config:

```
start on (net-device-up and runlevel [2345] and started td-agent)
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

env HOME="/var/nodes"

script
    chdir $HOME
    exec /usr/local/bin/node index.js -c app/config/live >> /var/log/node/server.log 2>> /var/log/node/server_error.log
end script
```

When I run:

```
initctl check-config node
```

I got this:

```
node
  start on: unknown job td-agent
```

When Server is booted, Node is down, but I can manually start it:

```
service node start
node start/running, process 1156
```

**EDIT:** If I remove `and started td-agent`, it is started on boot. But I need Node started after td-agent. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upstart seems to know nothing about `td-agent`. That is because upstart only recognizes jobs started by upstart.

Probably `td-agent` is started by a script in `/etc/init.d`. If that is the case, you can not use upstart to start `node` **and** have it depend on `td-agent`.

The solution is not to use upstart. You need to write a new script to `/etc/init.d` that starts `node`.

You must make it run after `td-agent` start script. When you have your script, use `update-rc.d` command to define when it starts.

Here is a link to an example minimal start script. It is for liferay but just fix the environment variables, and replace start() and stop() functions with your own definitions.
[Example liferay initd script](http://www.tidbitsofit.com/2010/10/liferay-initd-script.html).

Comment: Yes, `td-agent` is started by `/etc/init.d` script. I thought `upstart daemon` monitors processes for `td-agent`, but you say it has to be `upstart job` - sounds reasonable. Yea, I know how to create start / stop scripts. Thank you!